# What would cause parameter sniffing one one computer and not another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I just came across parameter sniffing in MSSQL today and used OPTION RECOMPILE to speed up a query that took 2.5 seconds with a parameter vs instant without. On a different developers machine they could run that exact same query without OPTION RECOMPILE and it ran super fast.

What could cause one machine to need OPTION RECOMPILE and another not?

Comment: Might want to ask this on dba too.

Comment: Same version/SP/SR/patch level? Same OS, hardware/drivers? Same db size? Stats up to date? ...etc...

Comment: @Preet you mean *instead*. Cross-posting is not encouraged at all.

Comment: By different machine are you talking about two different SQL Server instances or two different clients connecting to the same server?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you mean that both machines were connecting to the same server then there was probably a setting difference that caused the inappropriate plan to not be shared between the two connections.

In order for a connection to reuse a previously cached plan quite a few settings (plan cache keys) must be the same including `ANSI_NULLS`, `ARITHABORT`, `Language`, `DATEFIRST` and default schema (if the query relys on any implicit name resolution).

You can view these by looking at `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes` (the ones where `is_cache_key=1` need to be the same between connections).

A full list of the attributes where `is_cache_key=1` is

```
dbid_execute
required_cursor_options
compat_level
parent_plan_handle
date_format
language_id
status
merge_action_type
is_replication_specific
objectid
acceptable_cursor_options
date_first
set_options
user_id
dbid
optional_spid
optional_clr_trigger_objid
optional_clr_trigger_dbid
```

`set_options` and `cursor_options` are bit flags comprising a variety of options [as documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189472.aspx). In my experimentation  `user_id` actually refers to `schema_id(default_schema_name)` rather than `principal_id`.

Comment: Both machines were using sql managament studio and connecting to the same instance.

Comment: @chobo - Different logins? If so a different default language or a different default schema would be my first suspicion. But easy to check anyway (at the time) by finding the plan handle for the different plans and passing it to `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes`